# Is there a way to have a system wide meta key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I know that in terminal, one can remap right option -> meta.  This lets you do nice UNIX commands such as META-F (which goes forward a word), META-B, etc.  However, if you try doing OPTION-F outside of terminal, you get something like this: ƒ.

**Is there a way to disable the alt characters for the right option key to make it like terminal meta?**

The CTRL shortcuts (like CTRL-F or A) work well in OSX, but it doesn't seem possible to use the META ones.

Comment: Can you provide examples for using META outside of the Terminal?

Comment: Sure, I would use it a lot in most webapps.  Instead of pressing CTRL F and B to go letter by letter, I could skip through words by doing META F / B